# Redirect non-www to www (https) not working

Tags: nginx

I am trying to redirect all http and http calls to https:// www.example.com using nginx config file.

The problem is that the redirect do not work for http://example.com ->https://www.example.com

All others work.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  example.com;
    return       301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
listen 443;
ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /root/www.example.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /root/example.com.key;

        server_name www.example.com;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";
        access_log   /var/log/nginx/example.com.access.log;
        error_log    /var/log/nginx/example.com.error.log;

        root /var/www/example.com/htdocs;
        index index.php index.html;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

        location ~ .php$ {
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        }

    location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
    expires 30d;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }


    }
```

Comment: So what happens?

Answer (score 0):

You may try these, I guess its about using the exact statements

https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/how-to-redirect-http-traffic-to-https-in-nginx-and-apache/